# Binary Addition IEEE format

Tags: floating-point, precision, scientific-computing

I am trying to understand binary addition in the single precision IEEE format.

For example, consider the case

> `2^-20 + 2^-17`

How do I add them? Should I first convert them into decimal to the power 10 and do so? but then again i get 9 digits and since the computer can represent 7 digits, how do I get rid of the other two? And then how addition will be? Any reading materials would also be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Find a good source explaining the data format.

Extract the one bit sign, 8 bit exponent, and 23 bit stored mantissa from both numbers.

If any exponent is 0xff then that number is NaN (if the stored mantissa is non-zero) or Infinity (if the stored mantissa is 0). Look up what results you are supposed to return in all cases involving Infinity and NaN and return that result. Done.

Unless the exponent is 0 (zero or denormalised number) add the implicit leading 1 bit in position 23 of the mantissa, giving you the correct 24 bit mantissa.

Compare the exponents. Shift the number with the smaller mantissa to the right by the correct number of bits, but keep track of all the bits that were shifted out.

Add or subtract the mantissas, depending on the sign, including the bits that were shifted out.

If the mantissa and all the bits that were shifted out are zero then the result is +0 or -0. Check the IEEE rules to found which one. Only (-0) + (-0) gives -0, everything else +0. Done.

If bit 24 of the mantissa is set then shift the result to the right and increase the exponent by 1.

As long as bit 23 of the mantissa is cleared and the exponent is not zero shift the result to the left and decrease the exponent by 1.

If the highest bit of the bits that you shifted out of the mantissa is set, and if either there are more bits shifted out or the lowest bit of the mantissa is 1 then increase the mantissa by 1, and if bit 24 is set then shift it to the right by 1 bit and increase the exponent.

If the exponent is 0xff then the result is +Infinity or -Infinity. Done.

Otherwise clear bit 23 of the mantissa and combine sign, exponent and mantissa into a result.

Comment: Hmm thanks a lot for your answer? But how do I proceed to find the relative error then?

Comment: @user2792941: The same way you'd always compute relative error: `abs((approximate_value - exact_value) / exact_value)`. If you're unclear on how to compute a relative error, I'd suggest `math.stackexchange.com` as a more appropriate place.

Comment: This answer is missing all the details of how to round to 24 bits with the appropriate rounding mode (e.g., round-ties-to-even, or something else), and is also missing details about subnormals. Really, I don't think there's a good way to answer this question in SO format, unless we give a single canonical complete answer with all the details somewhere. And that seems redundant when this stuff is documented in so many other places.